# How to convert 8 character string into a single byte at a time to write to file in Java?

Tags: java, string, byte, encode, bit

I am trying to compress a binary number string into a file using bytes. Below is my attempt to convert this string by getting substrings of length 8 and trying to make those 8 characters into one single byte. Basically making each character a bit. Please let me know if there is a better way around this? I am not allowed to use any special libraries.

**Encode**

```
public static void encode(FileOutputStream C) throws IOException{

    String binaryString = "1001010100011000010010101011";
    String temp = new String();

    for(int i=0; i<binaryString.length(); i++){
        temp += binaryString.charAt(i);

        // once I get 8 character substring I write this to file
        if(temp.length() == 8){
            byte value = (byte) Integer.parseInt(temp,2);
            C.write(value);
            temp = "";
        }
        // remaining character substring is written to file
        else if(i == binaryString.length()-1){
            byte value = Byte.parseByte(temp, 2);
            C.write(value);
            temp = "";
        }
    }
    C.close();
}
```

**Decode**

```
Path path = Paths.get(args[0]);
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

for (byte bytes : data){
    String x = Integer.toString(bytes, 2);
}
```

These are the substrings that I'm encoding:

```
10010101
00011000
01001010
1011
```

Unfortunately when I decode I get the following:

```
-1101011
11000
1001010
1011
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the following

```
public static void encode(FileOutputStream out, String text) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length() - 7; i += 8) {
        String byteToParse = text.substring(i, Math.min(text.length(), i + 8));
        out.write((byte) Integer.parse(byteToParse, 2));
    }
    // caller created the out so should be the one to close it.
}
```

To print out the file

```
Path path = Paths.get(args[0]);
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

for (byte b : data) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(b & 0xFF, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check if this is what you looking for:

```
Byte bt = (byte)(int)Integer.valueOf("00011000", 2);
System.out.println(bt);
System.out.println(String.format("%8s",Integer.toBinaryString((bt+256)%256)).replace(' ', '0'));
```